# How to put multiple validation on a textfeild

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, uitextfield

i have textFeilds i put empty feild validation but i don't know how to put another validation(Multiple validation) like "Email is invalid" or whatever i want. This is just important code, all code is a lill lengthy

```
 final TextEditingController _emailControl = new TextEditingController();
   bool _validateEmail = false;




child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white,),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white,),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  hintText: "Email",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.mail_outline,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),

                labelText: 'Email',
                errorText: _validateEmail ? 'Email Can\'t Be Empty' : null,
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
                controller: _emailControl,
              ),
```

My registration button press is below

```
 onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {

                        _emailControl.text.isEmpty ? _validateEmail = true : _validateEmail = false;


                  if ( _validateEmail == false ){
                        _isLoading = true;
                      khan();

                        }
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TextFormField.

```
TextFormField(
validator(val):{
if(val.isEmpty){
return "This field cannot be empty",

}
else if(next conditon){
return ....
}
}
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white,),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white,),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  hintText: "Email",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.mail_outline,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),

                labelText: 'Email',
                errorText: _validateEmail ? 'Email Can\'t Be Empty' : null,
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
                controller: _emailControl,
              ),
```

And finally use form to validate the textfield.